# What is the difference between ( Save ) and ( Export ) in general computer?

Tags: excel, ms-word

What is the difference between ( Save ) and ( Export ) in general computer like if use them in word or excel . 
please easy definitions .

Comment: I think they are pretty self explanatory.. aren't they? One saves the file and other exports the contents of the file (format options available). Maybe I misunderstood the question.. can you elaborate on what's confusing you?

Comment: As I understand them, "Save" generally saves the file in a format that the software (word/excel/...) natively supports.  But "Export" will attempt to create the file in a format that is not normally native to the software (like Word -> Export as PDF)

Comment: @Doug But I can go File - > Save As and change the file type to .pdf and save it as a pdf just fine, what's the difference between doing that and selecting the File -> Export as PDF option?

Comment: My assumption there is that the Save As -> PDF could potentially be opened back up in Word and edited. Where the Export -> PDF may end up looking nicer but lose the ability to cleanly edit in the future.

Comment: This is off-topic on Stack Overflow as it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**save**: To save is to commit changes to a permanent state in a format that the application can natively utilize(keeps the file format).

To **export** is to change the data format so that another application can utilize it.(changes the format for example from png to jpg).